# Is there any way of making JHipster and meteor work together?

Tags: angularjs, meteor, real-time, jhipster, angular-meteor

We have a Monolithic application generated with Jhipster. We use gradle as build system. Now there is a requirement of implementing a real time data update in it. Meteor is a good open source option but stuck with configuration as I can not understand how to integrate it with JHipster.

Comment: Why down vote give explanation before make down vote

Answer (score 1):

If you want realtime data update, then use Websockets. Jhipster supports that. No need to add Meteor.

Comment: websocket implementation would be very cumbersome.Meteor provide a very easy implementation.It is also works on websocket.

Comment: The OP asked how to do X.  You are answering with how to do Y.  That doesn't answer his question.

Comment: I know my reputation does not allow me to post it as a comment, so had to post it as answer. Will try to be more specific next time. Thank you @Amy